# Is there a way to add a v4 Bot to Teams?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I'm beginning a project using Microsoft Bot Framework with Microsoft Teams. SDK V4 is already available but I saw that Teams uses V3 of the SDK only.
Is there a way to add a v4 Bot to Teams? or I can just use v3?

Comment: No, not as a teams bot. v4 is coming though and I believe is currently in developent. Having said that, you can incorporate a v4 bot into a channel. There is doco on how to do that ... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/add-bots

Comment: You could try your luck with the Preview version of the v4 Teams SDK which was released in January https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Microsoft-Teams-Blog/Introducing-the-Preview-Release-of-Net-Teams-Bot-Builder-v4-SDK/ba-p/324571.

Comment: @MattStannett how this SDK may help to publish? Looks like it is only feature for the development (Fetch a list of channels in a team / Fetch profile info about all members of a team / Fetch tenant-id from an incoming message to bot / Create 1:1 chat with a specific user / Mention a specific user)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use bot created with v4 SDK (Bot Builder SDK) in Teams, there is no problem around that.

As the comments mention, there are even official packages provided to use with this v4 to get more details about Teams, here: https://github.com/OfficeDev/BotBuilder-MicrosoftTeams-dotnet
It is not mandatory to use them to get a v4 bot in Teams, they provide additional functionalities.

If your question is about publishing a bot, the guidelines are provided in the documentation, here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/publishing/apps-publish